# overlapping characters in terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

The characters is gnome-terminal seem to have a different spacing for each one and some letters overlap. I tried changing the font and ticking the 'use system width and font' but I still get the same problem.
I also tried different terminals like tilda, terminator but the problem persists
Thanks in advance

Comment: are you using vim?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use a monofont to avoid this issue. Some other fonts *may* work *sometimes*, however, all monofont characters occupy the same amount of space.

Any "monospace" font will work well.

[en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font)

Also, here is a [list of monospaced fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces#Monospace).

[More monospaced fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samples_of_monospaced_typefaces).

[7-of-best-ubuntu-terminal-fixed-width](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/07/7-of-best-ubuntu-terminal-fixed-width.html)

Thanks @daltonfury42, you can change this setting by selecting Edit > Profile Preferences.

Under the General tab, select Custom Font and click on the font name to change.

Comment: Yeah, and you can set it by going to Edit -> Profile Preferences

Comment: Thanks for that, but the problem still persists. I don't think it has something to do with the fonts.

Comment: @JayakrishnaMenon I don't know then. I do know that when I use system width and fonts, the letters are all screwed up and they overlap each other. However, when I switch to a custom font such as monospace bold or courier, the problem goes away.